# AWS SageMaker S3 os.listdir() Access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I'm Stumped.

I took my TensorFlow model and moved it up into SageMaker to try it out.  I put my own data up into an s3 bucket, set all the IAM roles/access (or so I think).  I can read a file from s3.  I can push a new file to s3. I can read local directories from my SageMaker local directories.

**I cannot traverse my s3 bucket directories.**  I turned on logging and I get AccessDenied messages whenever I try access a URI of this format **'s3://my_bucketName_here/Directory_of_my_data/'**.

Here is what I've done:
I've confirmed that my notebook uses the AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-***
I've added AmazonSageMakerFullAccess Policy to that default role
I've subsequently added AmazonS3FullAccess Policy as well

I then created a bucket policy specifically granting s3:* access on the specific bucket to that specific role.

Heck, I eventually made the bucket public with ListObjects = Yes.

os.listdir() simply fails with file or directory not found and a lot message is created with AccessDenied. (TensorFlow libraries just didn't work, so I went with os.listdir() to simplify things.

Finally, I test my access from the Policy Simulator - I selected the Role mentioned above, selected to test s3 and selected all 69 items and they all passed.

But I continue to log AccessDenied and cannot actually list the contents of a directory from my SageMaker jupyter notebook.

I'm at a loss.  Thoughts?

EDIT:
Per suggestion below, I have the following:
bucket name contains sagemaker: '[redacted]-test-sagemaker'
Public access is off, and the only account is my root account.

`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::[redacted]-test-sagemaker"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::[redacted]-test-sagemaker/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}`
and
arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSageMakerFullAccess

Finally the bucket policy after the above failed:
`{
  "Id": "Policy1534116031672",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1534116026409",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[redacted]-test-sagemaker",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::[id]:role/service-role/AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-***"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to troubleshoot. Here are a few things to check:

0) Make sure the bucket is in the SageMaker region.

1) Include the string "sagemaker" in your bucket name (e.g., *my_bucketName_here-sagemaker*, SageMaker has out of the box access to buckets named this way.

2) Try using the SageMaker S3 [default_bucket()](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/session.py):

```
import sagemaker
s = sagemaker.Session()
s.upload_data(path='somefile.csv', bucket=s.default_bucket(), key_prefix='data/train')
```

3) Open terminal on the Notebook instance, to try to list your bucket using AWS CLI in bash:

```
aws iam get-user
aws s3 ls my_bucketName_here
```

Finally, pasting the bucket's access and resource policy in your question could help others to answer you.

Comment: Thanks! I started from scratch, pretty much default everything. 
0) N. Virginia 
1) bucket name: [redacted]-test-sagemaker 
2) I don't understand this one. I can do the upload just fine. That's part of my confusion. I can read in files and I can use the upload_data(). I cannot list objects (directory list). 
3) I cannot get-user, but I can list the directory just fine from command line.  **os.listdir() fails, glob.glob() returns empty, but ls from command line works just fine?**

Comment: Are you trying to os.listdir() on the S3 path? os.listdir() works over the local filesystem only. Generally to access S3 you use the boto3 sdk. Specifically for sagemaker when training starts SM auto copies the data you uploaded to S3 to the local filesystem, so tge training code can get it from the local filesystem. See sample notebooks for Tensorflow.

Comment: That makes sense!  Yes, I was trying to use os.listdir() on the S3 path.  I thought I'd just access the files remotely. I was doing pre-processing and not starting a training job yet.  I just wanted to run some python code in sagemaker jupyter.  I think I'm using the wrong tool for that part of the process perhaps.

Comment: I marked this as the answer as it may help others regarding checking on permissions.  As it turned out @Gili was most helpful.  I was trying to use os.listdir() to s3.  I used boto3 sdk and am completely functional now.  Thank you!